# Domain used for Gmail (G Suite/Workspace) Expired, re-bought via Cloudflare and now seeing weird SSL Certs

Tags: dns, https, cloudflare, google-workspace

So long story short: for a long time I've had domain (basic website + G-Suite email) for an LLC (let's say `example.com`) that I used to use for freelance gigs. I stopped doing much freelance stuff since I became employed by a company around 2 years ago. Still, I wanted to keep the domain, but idiot me forgot to renew the domain earlier this year and the domain expired and stopped existing.

Somehow my email with Google continued working as normal and I got no warnings AT ALL from Google about the underlying domain... I imagine perhaps because the domain wasn't snapped/kidnapped up by a reseller or any new owner to reset the DNS records?

Anyhow, as soon as I realized my domain had expired, I went to a new/different registrar (Cloudflare) and re-registered it ASAP. I setup the following DNS records (**real domain name and IP redacted)**:

[image: cloudflare-DNS-records]

**Now comes the weirdness:**

1. When I go to mysidehustle.com, I see the html page I'm expecting... BUT the page has an SSL certificate that I did NOT create or install. It's for the bare domain, and any subdomains (*/wildcard), and it's issued by Google Trust Services LLC. WTH?? I get that Cloudflare is proxying the domain, but why, how/where is it getting a Google SSL cert?!?
2. When I log into G-Suite/Workspace Domain admin area, I don't have many options as the domain just shows OK/active and "Verified" and the only thing I can do is "set up a redirect for www" and "Add Users".
3. Right now I am getting mail for the domain, and everything is working as normal (I think)

My question is what and why does #1 above happen?

Comment: It would be useful if you provided us with the actual domain - its difficult to grasp what you are saying.  For a start, if you don't renew a domain name, all services associated with it - including email - will stop working - so what you say makes little sense.  It might be useful for us to look at what DNS ACTUALLY thinks of your domain.

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can't do that for privacy reasons (it'd be trivial to dox me if I were to disclose my real business name). It'd be happy to run any DNS tests and redact my business name like I've done in the post above.

Comment: Im not willing to play 100 questions on your domain ( and trying to keep public info private is an anaethma to me) - but I have had a thought - could the presenting problem relate to browser caching?

Comment: @davidgo I'd rather not have my SE profile linked to my side hustle corp + my real PII. Also, it's 100% not a browser caching issue. No matter what browser or computer I use, incognito or not, I am able to reach the default nginx page I'm testing the website with and the SSL cert that shows up for website (when using HTTPS) is by Google Trust Service's CA. I'm just trying to understand why Google is proxying the site, and presenting it's SSL cert, not Cloudflare. I'd be happy to run any DNS tests recommended and relay back the results.

Comment: It sounds like your DNS setup is not how you think it is.  You should do a "whois" query to get the authorative nameservers, then do a dig query to get the A records referencing the authorative nameservers.   Unless you use Linux I need to leave this as an excercise to you.  (In Linux you can simply do **whois mysidehussle.com** to find the nameservers and other info, then pick a DNS server and do a **dig @name.server sidehustle.com A** to get the IP address.    I expect the nameservers wont be Cloudflares ones and your problem flows from there.

Comment: CloudFlare [uses several Certificate Authorities](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/i-want-to-change-ssl-to-cloudflare-now-google-trust-services-llc/490593) with [Google Trust Services](https://pki.goog/) being one of. DNS servers cached the `MX` record, so when you transferred the domain to CloudFlare, your `MX` record was picked up by CloudFlare. There would have been no interruption in mail delivery providing you maintained a Workspace account and quite a bit more time after expiration didn't occur. So, everything is as it should be.

Comment: @davidgo thanks, the nameservers are indeed Cloudflare's {lila|clayton}.ns.cloudflare.com, I think my issue might be moot though, given Dan's comment.

Comment: @dan thank you! I think you're right on the money! Cloudflare apparently does use GoogleTrustServices! Never would have imagined that. PS: I'll give you the answer if you post it below :)

Comment: No problem. I haven't been answering since becoming a mod so as to allow other users to build up their rep. Feel free to use that as an answer and accept it when you can so you'll earn some more too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this riddle turn out to be silly and trivial, for posterity:

Like Dan commented: CloudFlare [uses several Certificate Authorities](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/i-want-to-change-ssl-to-cloudflare-now-google-trust-services-llc/490593) with [Google Trust Services](https://pki.goog/) being one of. DNS servers cached the `MX` record, so when the domain was transferred to CloudFlare, the `MX` record was picked up by CloudFlare. There would have been no interruption in mail delivery provided one maintained a Workspace account and quite a bit more time after expiration didn't occur. So, everything is as it should